# Users can review and has reviews from other users solution

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

I'm using polymorphic association on my `Review` model for `User` and `Post`. 
However i would also make sense to have a owner for each review.

BY owner i mean a associated `user` model. But this bring problems on the table since **users can review and has reviews from other users**

What is the best way to go about. Any ideas of solutions are welcome.

**Review.rb**

```
belongs_to :reviewable, polymorphic: true
belongs_to :user # owner of the reviews
```

**User.rb**

```
  # reviews from others
  has_many :reviews, as: :reviewable, dependent: :destroy 
  has_many :reviews  # user written reviews
```

**Post.rb**

```
  has_many :reviews, as: :reviewable, dependent: :destroy
```

Comment: What's the problem, again?

Comment: "reviews from others" - do users review each other or what?

Comment: you are right @SergioTulentsev users can review and has reviews from other users

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Can you provide the table schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious problem is that you have two associations in your `User` model with the same name. One simple fix is to rename one of them. Since your `Post` already has a `reviews` association that matches a similar `reviews` polymorphic association, you could rename the user written reviews to be something like this:

```
has_many :reviews_by_me, class_name: 'Review'
```

By specifying the class name, Rails can then infer the rest of the information and get you the correct `Review` objects where `user_id` matches on your `User`.